# Differece between text and label in ggplots? Error in ggplotly : Too few points to calculate an ellipse

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I don't quite understand the difference between `text` and `label` in `ggplot2`.

For instance:

When I try to convert `ggplot2` object to `plotly` interactive object using `label` as tooltip, it worked; while I got the `Too few points to calculate an ellipse` error when using `text` as tooltip.

Why?

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, label = row.names(iris))) +
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill = Species), geom = "polygon", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.1, show.legend = F)

ggplotly(p)

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, text = row.names(iris))) +
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill = Species), geom = "polygon", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.1, show.legend = F) 

ggplotly(p2)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely the grouping. I have had no look at the `ggplot2` source code but I would guess that (in contrast to the `label` aes) the `text` attribute (which is no default ggplot2 aesthetic) is used to group the data, i.e. as you use map the `rownames` on `text` you end up with groups containing only one row of data. Hence you get a warning about too few points to draw an ellipse.

To prevent that you could or have to explicitly set the `group` aes in `stat_ellipse`:

```r
library(plotly)

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, text = row.names(iris))) +
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill = Species, group = Species), geom = "polygon", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.1, show.legend = F) 

ggplotly(p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Text requires previous label to be shown (as I understand the documentation): Therefore, if one goes to: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html; you 'll see that: [image]

With that, you see that the real problem is not the creation of the ellipse, but rather how your `geom_text()` is interpreted  in the function. If you write it as following, both ellipse and row.names appear in the graphic:

```
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, label = row.names(iris))) +
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse(aes(fill = Species), geom = "polygon", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.1, show.legend = F) 

p2+geom_text(check_overlap = T)
```

The result is the following:
[image]

Cheers!